# Unable to Display Products in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Our client is using custom search i.e., Searchperience at present they want to remove the custom search and enable the default magento search. While removing AOE_Searchperience related folders Products are not displaying at all. How can be this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have not removed all the files and there is an XML file that is pointing to a template that doesn't exist.

Are you concerned with the category page or the product page or both?

If everything is displaying on the *category* page except the products then I suggest you add a quick `echo('products would be here');` as the first line of code in the file /app/design/frontend/[your theme or base]/catalog/product/list.phtml

- if you can see that string in your shop you know you have identified the correct phtml file and you should check to see if the product collection is populated.
- if you do not see the string then you need to work out which list.phtml is being called by Magento. I would search my files for list.phtml but turning on Magento's system->configuration->developer->debug->template path hints (and add block names to hints) will expose which .phtml file is being called and what its block class is - that will help you flesh out if the wrong .phtml file is being used or if it is of the wrong class.

If the correct list.phtml is being called but the product collection is empty then there is something funny going on.

To remedy Magento behaving funny:

- log out of the admin area and log back into the admin area
- turn compilation off
- turn compilation back on
- re-index everything
- refresh all the Magento caches including the Magento cache and the cache storage
- refresh any external caches
- try to refresh the page and see if that helped.

If that didn't help, switch to the default Magento theme and repeat the steps above. If the product still aren't there even in the default theme then it suggests there are still some module files getting in the way or maybe the core files have been changed but that would be very odd. Start with the .phtml and the block class (discerned from the debug hints mentioned above and follow the code back until you figure out why the category page has an empty product collection)

If the default Magento theme does display the product then you know your fault is theme specific so turn your theme back on and study the file local.xml very very carefully.

Comment: Hi Malachy,
      Thanks for your reply.We tried with echo statement in "/app/design/frontend/[your theme or base]/catalog/product/list.phtml".But unable to print them. So as per your suggestion i went through this path 'Magento's system->configuration->developer->debug->template path hints (and add block names to hints)' but its not showing any list.phtml file.But with seeded Magento theme we are able to display the products.Can you please guide us where we have to change in our custom theme files..

Comment: With the template path hints and block names turned on, what blocks can you see? Look for [something eg Mage]_Catalog_Block_Category_View or the block with the template frontend/[yourtheme]/defaultcatalog/category/view.phtml if you find that, search your XML files for 'category.products' and ensure that that block has a child block called name="product_list" and that the file frontend/[yourtheme]/defaultcatalog/category/view.phtml is calling <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>